# (Cannot find symbol - method inputString(java.lang.String) Help why is there this error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String pet;
    pet = inputString("What pet do you own?");

    if (pet.equals("dog"));
    {
        System.out.println("Dogs are mans best friend!");
    }
    if(pet.equals("cat"));
    {
        System.out.println("Cats are very independent");
    }
    if(pet.equals("lion"));
    {
        System.out.println("I don't think that should be your pet mate...");
    }
}
```

Please help, my code is not taking the input of the user and just printing the `println` lines. also how can i use `else if` to this code.

Comment: There is no method called `inputString` you try to use. Do you miss the `Scanner` definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946664/scanner-only-reads-first-word-instead-of-line

Comment: Have you checked your braces amount?

Comment: please post all codes

Comment: I have added working code for you answering the doubts about `else if` as well. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] in a meantime.

Answer (score 4):

Well.. In Java we don't jave `inputString` method by default. You can use `Scanner`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What pet do you own?");
pet = sc.nextLine();
```

You should also have in mind, that the `if-else` statement in Java looks like the following:

```
if (<condition>) {  //<--there is no ;
    //do
} else {
    //do
}
```

There is no dedicated `else if` statement as `elif` or whatsever, but you can simply use:

```
if (<condition>) {  //<--there is no ;
    //do
} else if (<condition>){
    //do
} else if (<another condition>) {
    //do
} else {
    //do
}
```

Only `if` is obligatory. You can skip `else` statements. So in the end, your code should look like:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String pet;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What pet do you own?");
    pet = sc.nextLine();

    if (pet.equals("dog")) {
        System.out.println("Dogs are mans best friend!");
    } else if(pet.equals("cat")) {
        System.out.println("Cats are very independent");
    } else if(pet.equals("lion")) {
        System.out.println("I don't think that should be your pet mate...");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I didn't recognize your pet");
    }

}
```