# String can´t handle spaces?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, spaces

So i´m doing some exercises in Java and i have a problem with strings that doesn't seem to handle spaces all to well.

When i enter a name for example "Joe Smith" the "Smith" part is ending up in the variable program. And if i write "Economics major" in variable program the whole program crashes. (probably because points is a int variable)

It seems that spaces are making it crash or behave in a weird way. How should spaces work in this case?

```
import java.util.Scanner;




class Student {
String name;
String program;
int points; 

Scanner userScan = new Scanner(System.in);


String setName() {
    System.out.printf("Please enter name: ");
    String scan = userScan.next();
    name = scan;
    return name;
}

String setProgram() {
    System.out.printf("Please enter program: ");
    String scan = userScan.next();
    program = scan;
    return program;
}

int setPoints() {
    System.out.printf("Please enter points: ");
    int scan = userScan.nextInt();
    points = scan;
    return points;
}

void printStudent() {
    System.out.printf("Name: " + name + "\nProgram:" + program + "\nPoints" + points);    
}
}



public class Kap_2_Ovning_2Student {


public static void main(String[] args) {


   Student student1 = new Student();
   Student student2 = new Student();

   student1.setName();
   student1.setProgram();
   student1.setPoints();
   student1.printStudent();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946664/scanner-only-reads-first-word-instead-of-line

Comment: possible duplicate, but Karoi's answer here is better, more complete (IMHO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `new Scanner(System.in)` which by default uses whitespaces as a token delimiter. Each time you call `Scanner.next()` it only reads data until a delimiter is encountered. From the [`Scanner.next()` method javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

If you want to allow for spaces in your tokens you must change the delimiter, for example to split on new-line characters use:

```
new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\n*");
```

or use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaDoc for the `Scanner` [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), could you please check it, to broadly understand how it works.

I think main problem here is that you want to read whole line by calling `next()` method, instead of it you can use `nextLine()` method, for example.